# VSCode Rego Plugin opa evaluate not working as expected

Tags: visual-studio-code, open-policy-agent, rego

I'm learning OPA and rego.
I'm trying to write a simple policy and have the same evaluated through VSCode Plugin.

**Folder Structure:**

[image]

**learning.rego**

```
package learning

test {
    a := "test"
    a == "test"
}
```

**input.json**

```
{}
```

And when I choose "OPA: Evaluate Selection" option from the command pallete, I get the below error.

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "expected body but got *ast.Package"
    }
  ],
  "metrics": {
    "timer_rego_load_bundles_ns": 919639,
    "timer_rego_module_compile_ns": 481890,
    "timer_rego_module_parse_ns": 55722,
    "timer_rego_query_parse_ns": 22773
  }
}
```

But the same policy is working as expected in rego playground and evaluates to "true" as expected. What am I missing here?

Comment: @Devoops Do you have any idea on this one?

Answer (score 2):

Try running "Evaluate Package" instead of "Evaluate Selection", and it should work.

The Open Policy Agent extension for VSCode offers three ways of evaluating Rego code:

1. Evaluate Package

**This seems to be the one you want.** This parses the selected Rego code as an entire package. It expects the selection to begin with a Package declaration (e.g. `package learning`). If you select the entire Rego package and run "Evaluate Packages", it should work.

2. Evaluate Selection

This option evaluates *part* of a Rego package, so it expects the selection to begin with a Body (e.g. your `test` definition). If you just select `test` and its definition, it should work.

3. Partially Evaluate Selection

This final option is a [bit more complex](https://dzone.com/articles/open-policy-agent-part-ii-developing-policies). In essence, rather than evaluating the policy it returns the *conditions* under which the policy is satisfied. This is useful for building queries for external datastores, or for interacting with complex data.

Comment: Thank You @Will for the response. "Evaluate Package" works fine but I wanna evaluate policies as I write and I thought "Evaluate Selection" would be a right choice but it is not working as expected. I highlighted the policy body as suggested and running evaluate selection return a similar error as above.

Selected Policy:
`
test {
    a := "test"
    a == "test"
}
`

Error Response:
`
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "expected body but got *ast.Rule"
    }
  ],
  "metrics": {
    // redacted to save space.
  }
}
`

Comment: I feel the plugin's "Evaluate Package" is not working as expected or I'm running it in a totally wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

In vs code press ctrl+p and search for >OPA: Evaluate Package and enter you'll see the result.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To use `Evaluate Selection`

Double click on the policy name, in your case, `test`

Now run `Evaluate Selection`
It should work fine.

Refer to this website for more info: [link](https://sangkeon.github.io/opaguide/chap2/installandusage.html)

For your specific case, read up Chapter 2.